# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments

Tags: spring-mvc, weblogic, maven-3

I have developed a maven project (spring) in eclipse ide.The project is running in `tomcat7` but not running in `weblogic server 10.3.6`.

I am getting the below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/Class
```

Answer (score 1):

A `NoSuchMethodError` is almost always due to **conflicting library versions**. In this case I'm guessing there are multiple versions of spring libraries in the two projects.

```
Weblogic pulls spring jar of some different version from its own also apart from the version you have in your application.
```

You should have below code in your **weblogic.xml** to make your application up an drunning.

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
           <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
           <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
           <package-name>org.slf4j.helpers.*</package-name>
           <package-name>org.slf4j.impl.*</package-name>
           <package-name>org.slf4j.spi.*</package-name>
           <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
           <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
           <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
           <package-name>org.apache.commons.*</package-name>
           <package-name>org.apache.xmlbeans.*</package-name>
           <package-name>javassist.*</package-name>
           <package-name>org.joda.*</package-name> 
           <package-name>org.codehaus.jackson.*</package-name>      
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>

        <wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>

    </wls:container-descriptor>
```

It will prefer your application jars only.
This is from my application, you can add/remove the above entries according to your project needs.